# Postback when validating ASP.NET MVC Form

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I created a web form form using asp.net mvc scaffolding and it does not work client side validation without postback. [Required()] is postbacking and [EmailAddress] validator is validating in client side. Im using visual studio 2013 and asp.net mvc 5 with ef6. 
this id my model class :

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class Tutor
{
    public Tutor()
    {
        this.Examinations = new HashSet<Examination>();
    }


    public decimal TutorID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter First Name.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Last Name.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1 ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Address Line 1.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2 ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Address Line 2.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 3 ")]
    public string Address3 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telephone 1 ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Telephone No.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Tel1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telephone 2 ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Tel2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter E Mail Address.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EMail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsConfirmed { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Examination> Examinations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my controller Create() methods in controller:

```
    // GET: /Default1/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Default1/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="TutorID,FirstName,LastName,Address1,Address2,Address3,Tel1,Tel2,EMail,Password,IsConfirmed")] Tutor tutor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tutors.Add(tutor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tutor);
    }
```

This Is view for create...

```
  @model WebApplication4.Models.Tutor

  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Create";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <h2>Create</h2>


   @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <div class="form-horizontal">
      <h4>Tutor</h4>
      <hr />
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address2)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address3, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address3)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tel1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tel1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tel1)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tel2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tel2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tel2)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EMail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EMail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EMail)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I want to validate all the things in client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to use jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.

Once you load the form, using jquery on document ready you should parse the form

```
//file: your view file
@model Tutor

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#frm1"));
}

function onSubmit(e) {
  $("#frm1").validate(); // this will validate the form and show the validation messages
  if($("#frm1").valid()) {
     $("#frm1").submit(); // submits the form
  }
  return false;//prevent default submit of form by returning false.
  //also e.preventDefault() can be used.
}
</script>

//for understanding purpose using the plain form tag.
//one can use  @using (Html.BeginForm())

<form id="frm1" onsubmit="onSubmit();">
<!-- your content goes here -->
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you load jquery.validate.js liberary properly

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

**At end of your page**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```